# How to change a plugins url from localhost to website

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, plugins

Im wondering, I have a website tashapedersen.com

If you click on the "Events" Tab, it still thinks that its in localhost,

Im not sure where to look to change the url, or how localhost is being called upon in this instance.

1. With the Events Calendar Plugin, I dont get to edit the page as I would a normal wordpress page, but actually if you put in tashapedersen.com/events then it opens up the page, so I dont think its on the plugins end. Theres a disconnect somewhere.
2. When I uploaded the site, I "found and replaced" all the localhost titles in the database already.
3. Im wondering if this is maybe somewhere in phpmyadmin?

Would really appreciate some help here in finding where to fix this and how to fix it if you know.

Thank you

James

Here is a bit of the template-loader.php

```
if ( defined('WP_USE_THEMES') && WP_USE_THEMES )
/**
 * Fires before determining which template to load.
 *
 * @since 1.5.0
 */
do_action( 'template_redirect' );

if ( 'HEAD' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && apply_filters(   'exit_on_http_head', true ) )
exit();


do_action( 'do_robots' );
return;
elseif ( is_feed() ) :
do_feed();
return;
elseif ( is_trackback() ) :
include( ABSPATH . 'wp-trackback.php' );
return;
endif;

if ( defined('WP_USE_THEMES') && WP_USE_THEMES ) :
  $template = false;
if     ( is_embed()          && $template = get_embed_template()          )      :
elseif ( is_404()            && $template = get_404_template()            ) :
elseif ( is_search()         && $template = get_search_template()         ) :
elseif ( is_front_page()     && $template = get_front_page_template()     ) :
elseif ( is_home()           && $template = get_home_template()           ) :
elseif ( is_post_type_archive() && $template = get_post_type_archive_template() ) :
elseif ( is_tax()            && $template = get_taxonomy_template()       ) :
elseif ( is_attachment()     && $template = get_attachment_template()     ) :
    remove_filter('the_content', 'prepend_attachment');
elseif ( is_single()         && $template = get_single_template()         ) :
elseif ( is_page()           && $template = get_page_template()           ) :
elseif ( is_singular()       && $template = get_singular_template()       ) :
elseif ( is_category()       && $template = get_category_template()       ) :
elseif ( is_tag()            && $template = get_tag_template()            ) :
elseif ( is_author()         && $template = get_author_template()         ) :
elseif ( is_date()           && $template = get_date_template()           ) :
elseif ( is_archive()        && $template = get_archive_template()        ) :
elseif ( is_paged()          && $template = get_paged_template()          ) :
else :
    $template = get_index_template();
endif;

if ( $template = apply_filters( 'template_include', $template ) ) {
    include( $template );
} elseif ( current_user_can( 'switch_themes' ) ) {
    $theme = wp_get_theme();
    if ( $theme->errors() ) {
        wp_die( $theme->errors() );
    }
}
  return;
endif;
```

Comment: you need to edit particular a href=""  for event tab in the index.html page. Do inspect element and view it.

Comment: Thanks, Im looking through my index, maybe I can show you through code. See its all in PHP so one file refers to two which refer to four and so on.

Comment: Theres index.php which leads to wp-blog-header.php which leads to both wp-load.php & template-loader.php, wp-load.php leads to both wp-config.php & wp-settings.php

Comment: oh i guess it is template loader.php.  you can search for menu-item-207 in those files. because list id of event is menu-item-207

Comment: But would that be true, if the events are being handled by the event calendar plugin? I didnt see the item in the code, do you see the code? Is there any place where I could make a case for the event calendar to be considered, or what would I do?

Thank you